# Manufacture a process who create empty log's line

Tags: c#, syslog

As part of my job, i'm using C# and visual studio, and visual syslog.
I need to manufacture a process who create empty log's line. Someone have an idea\some direction of how doing that ?

those are the value that sends to syslog server: (i don't understand how to cause the values to being empty)

```
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(67):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "Date", date) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(68):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "Time", time) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(69):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "ID", eventId) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(70):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "User", userName) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(71):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "Machine", machine) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(72):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "ProcessPath", processPath) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(73):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "ProcessFlags", processFlags) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(74):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "PID", processId) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(75):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "Operation", operation) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(76):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "TrustZone", trustZone) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(77):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "Destination", destination) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(78):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "Location", location) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(79):      LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "Source", source);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(96):      log += LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "Hash(MD5)", hashMD5);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(97):      log += LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "File ID", hashFileId);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(100): log += LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "Comments", comments);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(101): log += LogDataFormatter(eventPrefix + "Access", desiredAccess, true);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(182):     LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "DateTime", dateTime) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(183):     LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "Event", eventType) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(184):     LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "User", userName) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(185):     LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "Machine", machine) +
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(186):     LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "Path", path);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(209):     log += LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "TrustZone", trustZoneType);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(210):     log += LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "Hash(MD5)", hash);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(211):     log += LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "Flag", processFlags);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(222): log += LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "ID", pid);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(226):         log += LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "Argument", processSegmentList[i]);
  T:\RedLight\Client\HelperC\BZLogger.cpp(229): log += LogDataFormatter(processPrefix + "Severity", severity, true);
```

Comment: Could elaborate on what exactly you would like to have for a result?

Comment: how do i run this code ?:

HMODULE hm = LoadLibrary("am.dll"); GW RL_LogA = (GW)RL_LogA(hm, "RL_LogA"); RL_LogA(30000, "[EVENTID=896] [OPERATION=] [COMPUTER-NAME=URIELG] [USER-NAME=urielg] [PID=0] [PROCESS-PATH=''] [TRUST-ZONE=0] [PROCESS-FLAGS=0x0000] [SOURCE=] [DESTINATION='BufferZone is not fully active: Service=True, BZRPCSS=False, BZDCOM=False, WinBorder=False, BZBHO=False, UserSession=True'] [LOCATION=] [MD5=] [COMMENTS=] [DesiredAccess=0x00000000])")